# When NOT to use Formik's FastField?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

In the docs of Formik's [FastField](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/fastfield) it have alot of when you should use it and how it works, but is there a case where you shouldn't use?

Because if in somecases `FastField` is faster and other cases it doesn't make any difference, why not always use `FastField`? Is there a case where using `Field` is better than `FastField`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

FastField has a shouldComponentUpdate which is 'concerned' about changes to only its own props.

If, your use-case, requires field to re-render because of any other change then don't go for FastField. **Even if some other prop change, your component won't be updated.**

Also, as per the docs, performance issues due to Formik Field's re-render might surface only on cases where the form is huge (>30 Fields). They recommend using FastFields for >30 Fields only.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(props: FastFieldInnerProps<Values, Props>) {
    if (this.props.shouldUpdate) {
      return this.props.shouldUpdate(props, this.props);
    } else if (
      props.name !== this.props.name ||
      getIn(props.formik.values, this.props.name) !==
        getIn(this.props.formik.values, this.props.name) ||
      getIn(props.formik.errors, this.props.name) !==
        getIn(this.props.formik.errors, this.props.name) ||
      getIn(props.formik.touched, this.props.name) !==
        getIn(this.props.formik.touched, this.props.name) ||
      Object.keys(this.props).length !== Object.keys(props).length ||
      props.formik.isSubmitting !== this.props.formik.isSubmitting
    ) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```